# 404 Error on custom cgi on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, web-config, cgi, iis-8

we are in trouble to configure custom cgi (modulev3.exe) by Paybox System

we follow :  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/fr-fr/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/29cdf931-4a86-4fa0-b2ae-c3081e8559c0

but that make 404 Error

ServiceDefinition.csdef :

```
<Startup>
 <Task commandLine="EnableIsapi.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
</Startup>
```

EnableIsapi.cmd :

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:isapiCgiRestriction /+"[path='%RoleRoot%\approot\cgi-bin\modulev3.exe',description='Paybox',allowed='True']"
```

Web.config :

```
<system.webServer>
   <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Write, Script, Execute">
     <remove name="CGI-exe" />
      <add name="CGI-exe" path="*.exe" verb="*" modules="CgiModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Execute" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
          <fileExtensions>
            <add fileExtension=".exe" allowed="true" />
          </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
      <isapiCgiRestriction>
        <add allowed="true" path="%RoleRoot%\approot\cgi-bin\modulev3.exe" description="PAYBOXMODULE" />
      </isapiCgiRestriction>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: When exactly do you get the 404 error ?